# Jenkins Pipeline and Groovy. Iterate through things in parallel until they are done

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am sketching out a Jenkins pipeline. I can run tests in groups of 8 on 5 parallel nodes until they are done.

Below I'm simplifying this to do groups of 8 on 3 nodes.

I want to know if I can loop stages in a pipeline to complete them until I've gone through each.

```
TESTS.collate(8).collate(3).each {
  parallel {
    stage('run tests 1') {
      agent { label 'node1' }
      runTests(it[0])
    }
    stage('run tests 2') {
      agent { label 'node2' }
      runTests(it[1])
    }
    stage('run tests 3') {
      agent { label 'node3' }
      runTests(it[2])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be declarative Pipeline or is scripted possible as well?

Comment: Declarative. I got it working. I will want to share a scrubbed version with nothing company specific when I get a chance. Especially since I have questions about how I did it. I whitelisted a lot of Groovy methods and classes and my friend in ops and I were discussing security implications when we decide to make this production ready.

Comment: Would be curious to see. About the whitelisting: You may overcome this if you wrap the respective methods in a global shared library - if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relevant part of my Jenkinsfile

```
                def splitNBTests = NB_TESTS.split("\n").toList().collate(7)
                println(splitNBTests)
                if (!params.runCukes) {
                    echo "SKIPPING NEW BUSINESS RUN IN OZ JOB DUE TO DISABLED PARAMETER"
                } else {
                    SUITE_RUN_ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                    def commands = splitNBTests.collect { def testsForNode ->
                        createCmdLineForCukes(testsForNode, PROFILE)
                    }
                    try {
                        TAGS = '"@regression ~@wip"'
                        SCENARIO_COUNT = "${DIRECTORY_CHANGE} && bundle && bundle exec rake run_scenario_count[${TAGS},${PROFILE}] SUITE_RUN_ID=${SUITE_RUN_ID}"
                        sh(returnStdout: true, script: SCENARIO_COUNT)
                        def stepsForParallel = [:]
                        commands.toList().eachWithIndex { def myCommand, int i ->
                            stepsForParallel["RunTests${i}"] = {
                                stage("RunTests${i}") {
                                    node {
                                        label 'grange-jenkins-slave'
                                        sh("mount -a")
                                        sh(myCommand)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        parallel stepsForParallel
```

I have our Jenkins Master on Kubernetes with the Kubernetes plugin to dynamically scale slave pods. For our current regression run this could bring up about 24 nodes if we run 7 tests on each but we limit it to run 10 at a time for now.

The 'white-listing' I was talking about was under In-Process Script Approval. I currently have it set to `staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String`.

I'm guessing that should be locked down a bit more. Tips appreciated. I come to Groovy from Ruby and hacked this together with minimum time to really learn Groovy. I'll say it was similar enough and it was definitely useful to get help from the Groovy community so I could learn of the Groovy equivalent to `#each_slice` in Ruby, `#collate`. Thanks!